# Why is the new tab text aligning to the right?

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol

When I create a new tab during runtime, the text for the tab aligns itself to the right. When I create another tab, the previous new tab aligns the text correctly, and the new tab aligns to the right.

Here is the source code...

```vb
Private Sub NewTab_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NewTab.Click
        Dim t As New TabPage
        Dim newtab As New Tab
        Dim TabCount As Integer

        TabCount = TabBrowser.TabPages.Count

        newtab.Show()
        newtab.TopLevel = False
        newtab.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        t.Controls.Add(newtab)
        TabBrowser.TabPages.Add(t)
        TabBrowser.TabPages(TabCount).Text = BrwsMain.DocumentTitle
    End Sub
```

I want the text to align in the centre like the previous tab.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmTzP.png

Comment: Hard to guess when you don't document your Win10 version.  I keep mine updated on its regular pace and see no sign of this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to do the trick...

```vb
TabBrowser.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Normal
TabBrowser.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed
```

Not really something I wanted to do as it's sloppy programming. But seems to be the only way to fix it.

Comment: Accept your answer as the solution for this question, please.

Comment: @wEight : The OP cannot accept his own answer until 48 hours has passed since he asked his question. This is to give others a chance to answer it as well.